# Date string to date

Tags: excel, matlab, date, datetime

I am fairly new to Matlab and therefore have some problems related of importing data.

I want to import GDP data and then plot it to time. I was able to import it and translate to string dates. Now I would like to convert it back to my target Matrix. However, I just see values 48 or 49 in my target matrix.

My code is as follows:

```
    AUSGDP = zeros(228,2);
    GDP = xlsread('AUDGDP.xlsx');
    GDP = GDP(1:228,1) + 693960;
    datestring = datestr(GDP,'mm/yyyy');
    AUSGDP(228,1) = datestring(228,1)
```

The Data (right after `xlsread('AUDGDP.xlsx')` looks somehow like this:

```
Date  | % Change
------|---------
21794 | 0
21885 | 1.300000
21976 | 1.500000
22068 | 1.400000
```

Comment: Can you please post an executable example? (replace `GDP = xlsread('AUDGDP.xlsx');` with some of the data that was read (e.g `GDP(1) = 123; GDP(2) = 456;`...).

Comment: I will edit it in above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting 48 or 49, is because datestring(228,1), return the value of the first character in the string.
The fist character of '09/2016' is '0', and '0' value is 48 (in ASCII).

Example:
`s = '09/2016'`
`s(1)` equals '0'.
Convert to double: `double(s(1))` equals 48.

I suppose you meant to take the month as number (opposed to string).

One way is to get fist two characters, and convert string to double (to number):
`s = '09/2016'`
`month_str = s(1:2); % month_str = '09'`
`month_num = str2num(month_str) %Convert string to number.`

Instead of using `datestr` function, you can use `datevec`.
`datevec` convert date and time to vector of components (all components are numbers, not strings).
`datevec('09/2016', 'mm/yyyy')`
Return: `2016           9           1           0           0           0`

In case you need only the month, you can use:
`[~, m, ~, ~, ~, ~] = datevec('09/2016', 'mm/yyyy')`
The result is `m = 9`

In your code you can use it as follows:

```
AUSGDP = zeros(228,2);
GDP = xlsread('AUDGDP.xlsx');
GDP = GDP(1:228,1) + 693960;
datestring = datestr(GDP,'mm/yyyy');
%AUSGDP(228,1) = datestring(228,1)
[~, m, ~, ~, ~, ~] = datevec(datestring, 'mm/yyyy'); %m is months column as numbers.
AUSGDP(228,1) = m;
```